# Why does this javascript/jQuery not submit the html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to submit a HTML based form using Javascript/jQuery, but it seems not to submit anything.

And my HTML form is now;

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" id="loginForm" action="login.php">
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

My Javascript code is now;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        var $url = $form.attr('action');
        var $username = $("#username");
        var $password = $("#password");

        if ($username.val().length > 0 && $password.val().length > 0) {
            var $posting = $.post(
                $url, {
                    name: $username.val(),
                    password: $password.val()
                }
            );

            $posting.done(function(data) {
                alert("Username: " + data.name + "\nPassword: " + data.password);
            });
        } else {
            alertify.warning("Username or password is empty!");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Good edit! Would be better with consistent, readable indentation and a more thorough description of what you've diagnosed so far.

Comment: Where/how specifically is it failing?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you step through in the debugger, does the code execute as you expect?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it have the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: From the docs: we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Look at the code. The OP is replacing the real submit with a call to `$.post`.

Comment: so what is the console saying is there a post request or not?

Comment: It should send the login data (username and password) to the login php script (login.php) but that seems not to happen, the warning "Username or password is empty!" does appear, even if there's anything inserted as input.   

There's an error in the Javascript console;
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have these selectors:

```
var $username = $("#username");
var $password = $("#password");
```

But there are no such matching elements in the markup.  So this condition will always be `false`:

```
if ($username.val().length > 0 && $password.val().length > 0) {
```

Either change the markup to match the selectors (by adding `id="username"` and `id="password"` to the relevant HTML elements), or change the selectors to match the markup:

```
var $username = $("input[name=username]");
var $password = $("input[name=password]");
```

Or, even better, as [pointed out in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/60607637?noredirect=1), since the `submit` handler already has a reference to the form by way of `$(this)` then you can search on that:

```
var $username = $form.find("input[name=username]");
var $password = $form.find("input[name=password]");
```

This can be especially useful given that `name` doesn't have to be unique in the DOM (though is *very often* unique in a `form`).

Comment: Or even `$form.find("input[name=username]")` to keep it nicely contained.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Good point, I'll add that to the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Experminator: "freezes" where/how?

Comment: @Experminator: And when you step through the code in the debugger, is there a specific operation which is "freezing"?  Is the browser unresponsive entirely?  Is it just a styling problem with the button?  Please be specific.

Comment: @Experminator: And again: Your question cannot rely on off-site content.

Comment: @David When I submit the form using the 'Sign in' button, my webpage completly freezes and after certain time it crashes.

No logs in the console though.
![Result](https://i.gyazo.com/6d24c9c0e958eef6cee4c099e318fbf4.png)

Comment: @Experminator: The code is not a black box.  You are definitely going to want to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Step through the code as it executes using the browser's debugging tools and find out more specifically what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

the issue on your code is that you are not referencing the target input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

As you can see, you use **name** instead of **id**, if you are using **name** on your html elements, you need to change this line of your code:

```
    var $username = $('[name="username"]');
    var $password = $('[name="password"]'");
```

But to make your work simpler, just add id attribute on your elements :)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```